# Google Drive's html to Docs document conversion corrupted since 2 Oct

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

We have been using Google Drive SDK for our app.

Since 2 October, when our app tries to create a Google Docs native document by uploading a html file contains img tags, the result become partly corrupted. Although the upload request finishes without error, all the images in the html are lost in the created document.

The behavior is not usual. For nearly two years, basically, the conversion for document insertion had interpreted the img tags and created embedded images. It seems like a server side problem exists.

Is it a known issue and would be fixed?

Or, is there something I'm missing and it is correct behavior?

**[About the htmls we use]**

- The htmls for upload are based on exported "text/html" files from existing Google Docs documents.
- All the img tags have src attribute with absolute url. They start with https and all of them are links on googleusercontent.com.
- Apart from the img tags, all the html tags seems to be handled as before.

**[How to reproduce the problem]**

This problem can be reproduced by using DriveSample app in "Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C". Modify "DriveSampleWindowController.m" to force document conversion turned on (i.e., query.convert=YES;) just before uploading a file to Drive.

1. Download an existing Docs document with images as html.
2. Upload it as a new document to Google Drive (with document conversion turned on).
3. Open the uploaded document in 2 with Google Docs web editor. All images would be lost in the document. Also, no spinning wheels will be shown for the lost image areas.

Comment: This occurs using direct REST calls as well as the client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems fixed on the server side within the last half day. Thank you for fixing it, Google.