# Images disappear after uploading a doc with conversion

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

When using the 'insert' DRIVE API function, in combination with the multi-part type. The images that are in my document appear to be stripped? It's just normal HTML with a img tag.

Some 2 weeks ago it worked fine, but somehow it stopped working.

I can provide sample HTML and the result GDocs file if needed.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems it starts from 1 or 2 Oct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156370